# Gymnopedie no 1 key signature

Tags: key-signatures

I have a handbell arrangement of Gymnopedie with Bb in the signature.  Normally you know that means key of Fmaj.   Is it Fmaj?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this key signature used in Gymnopedie 1 - F major or D major?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/125286/what-is-this-key-signature-used-in-gymnopedie-1-f-major-or-d-major)

Comment: I wonder what the money's like arranging Satie for handbells.

Answer (score 3):

The original is in D major. If your version is pitched a 3rd higher than this, it's in F major.[image]

Or if it's at the original pitch, but with a D minor key signature of one flat, it may be copying a Faber edition which prefers to define the key by the final D minor chord rather than all the preceding D major ones!

Comment: There do seem to exist editions which write the piece at original pitch but with a key signature of one flat: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/125286/what-is-this-key-signature-used-in-gymnopedie-1-f-major-or-d-major?rq=1

Comment: Well, one edition!   That  Faber edition disagrees with Satie's manuscript.   An error, or an editor who couldn't come to terms with a minor final chord, like a reverse tierce de picardie?  But thanks, I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Indeed! - I'm definitely not claiming it's sensible :) But it's another possibility when someone mentions a version with that key signature - if the original poster gives us an image, then we'll know for sure :)